# Google Reviews Not Being Fetched

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My google reviews are not being fetched. I've tried the code below but it doesn't work. I've created an api and put this in along with my placeid in all of the code below but nothing displays.

I followed multiple tutorials which all give basically the same code. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have any suggestions on how to implement this in an easier way?

html:

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/google-places.js "></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=[API_KEY]"></script>

<script>   
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
      $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({         
         placeId: '[PLACES_ID]',        
         render: ['reviews'],         
         min_rating: 3,       
         max_rows: 0      
       });  
   });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="google-reviews"></div>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
/* https://github.com/peledies/google-places */
(function($) {

    var namespace = 'googlePlaces';

    $.googlePlaces = function(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
              placeId: 'PLACEID' // placeId provided by google api documentation
            , render: ['reviews']
            , min_rating: 3
            , max_rows: 0
            , map_plug_id: 'map-plug'
            , rotateTime: false
            , shorten_names: true
            , schema:{
                  displayElement: '#schema'
                , type: 'Store'
                , beforeText: 'Google Users Have Rated'
                , middleText: 'based on'
                , afterText: 'ratings and reviews'
                , image: null
                , priceRange: null
            }
            , address:{
                displayElement: "#google-address"
              }
            , phone:{
                displayElement: "#google-phone"
            }
            , staticMap:{
                  displayElement: "#google-static-map"
                , width: 512
                , height: 512
                , zoom: 17
                , type: "roadmap"
            }
            , hours:{
                displayElement: "#google-hours"
            }
        };

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {}

        var $element = $(element),
             element = element;

        plugin.init = function() {
          plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
          plugin.settings.schema = $.extend({}, defaults.schema, options.schema);
          $element.html("<div id='" + plugin.settings.map_plug_id + "'></div>"); // create a plug for google to load data into
          initialize_place(function(place){
            plugin.place_data = place;

            // Trigger event before render
            $element.trigger('beforeRender.' + namespace);

            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('rating') > -1){
              renderRating(plugin.place_data.rating);
            }
            // render specified sections
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('reviews') > -1){
              renderReviews(plugin.place_data.reviews);
              if(!!plugin.settings.rotateTime) {
                  initRotation();
              }
            }
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('address') > -1){
              renderAddress(
                  capture_element(plugin.settings.address.displayElement)
                , plugin.place_data.adr_address
              );
            }
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('phone') > -1){
              renderPhone(
                  capture_element(plugin.settings.phone.displayElement)
                , plugin.place_data.formatted_phone_number
              );
            }
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('staticMap') > -1){
              renderStaticMap(
                  capture_element(plugin.settings.staticMap.displayElement)
                , plugin.place_data.formatted_address
              );
            }
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('hours') > -1){
              renderHours(
                  capture_element(plugin.settings.hours.displayElement)
                , plugin.place_data.opening_hours
              );
            }

            // render schema markup
            addSchemaMarkup(
                capture_element(plugin.settings.schema.displayElement)
              , plugin.place_data
            );

            // Trigger event after render
            $element.trigger('afterRender.' + namespace);

          });
        }

        var capture_element = function(element){
          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            return element;
          }else if(typeof element == 'string'){
            try{
              var ele = $(element);
              if( ele.length ){
                return ele;
              }else{
                throw 'Element [' + element + '] couldnt be found in the DOM. Skipping '+element+' markup generation.';
              }
            }catch(e){
              console.warn(e);
            }
          }
        }

        var initialize_place = function(c){
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(plugin.settings.map_plug_id));

          var request = {
            placeId: plugin.settings.placeId
          };

          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

          service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              c(place);
            }
          });
        }

        var sort_by_date = function(ray) {
          ray.sort(function(a, b){
            var keyA = new Date(a.time),
            keyB = new Date(b.time);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
            if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
            return 0;
          });
          return ray;
        }

        var filter_minimum_rating = function(reviews){
          for (var i = reviews.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(reviews[i].rating < plugin.settings.min_rating){
              reviews.splice(i,1);
            }
          }
          return reviews;
        }

        var renderRating = function(rating){
            var html = "";
            var star = renderAverageStars(rating);
            html = "<div class='average-rating'><h4>"+star+"</h4></div>";
            $element.append(html);
        }

        var shorten_name = function(name) {
          if (name.split(" ").length > 1) {
            var xname = "";
            xname = name.split(" ");
            return xname[0] + " " + xname[1][0] + ".";
          }
        }

        var renderReviews = function(reviews){
          reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
          reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);
          var html = "";
          var row_count = (plugin.settings.max_rows > 0)? plugin.settings.max_rows - 1 : reviews.length - 1;
          // make sure the row_count is not greater than available records
          row_count = (row_count > reviews.length-1)? reviews.length -1 : row_count;
          for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--) {
            var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating);
            var date = convertTime(reviews[i].time);
            if(plugin.settings.shorten_names == true) {
              var name = shorten_name(reviews[i].author_name);
            } else {
              var name = reviews[i].author_name + "</span><span class='review-sep'>, </span>";
            };
            html = html+"<div class='review-item'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+name+"<span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"
          };
          $element.append(html);
        }

        var renderHours = function(element, data){
          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            var html = "<ul>";
            data.weekday_text.forEach(function(day){
              html += "<li>"+day+"</li>";
            });
            html += "</ul>";
            element.append(html);
          }
        }

        var renderStaticMap = function(element, data){
          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            var map = plugin.settings.staticMap;
            element.append(
              "<img src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"+
                "?size="+map.width+"x"+map.height+
                "&zoom="+map.zoom+
                "&maptype="+map.type+
                "&markers=size:large%7Ccolor:red%7C"+data+"'>"+
              "</img>");
          }
        }

        var renderAddress = function(element, data){
          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            element.append(data);
          }
        }

        var renderPhone = function(element, data){
          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            element.append(data);
          }
        }

        var initRotation = function() {
            var $reviewEls = $element.children('.review-item');
            var currentIdx = $reviewEls.length > 0 ? 0 : false;
            $reviewEls.hide();
            if(currentIdx !== false) {
                $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).show();
                setInterval(function(){
                    if(++currentIdx >= $reviewEls.length) {
                        currentIdx = 0;
                    }
                    $reviewEls.hide();
                    $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).fadeIn('slow');
                }, plugin.settings.rotateTime);
            }
        }

        var renderStars = function(rating){
          var stars = "<div class='review-stars'><ul>";

          // fill in gold stars
          for (var i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
            stars = stars+"<li><i class='star'></i></li>";
          };

          // fill in empty stars
          if(rating < 5){
            for (var i = 0; i < (5 - rating); i++) {
              stars = stars+"<li><i class='star inactive'></i></li>";
            };
          }
          stars = stars+"</ul></div>";
          return stars;
        }

        var renderAverageStars = function(rating){
            var stars = "<div class='review-stars'><ul><li><i>"+rating+"&nbsp;</i></li>";
            var activeStars = parseInt(rating);
            var inactiveStars = 5 - activeStars;
            var width = (rating - activeStars) * 100 + '%';

            // fill in gold stars
            for (var i = 0; i < activeStars; i++) {
              stars += "<li><i class='star'></i></li>";
            };

            // fill in empty stars
            if(inactiveStars > 0){
              for (var i = 0; i < inactiveStars; i++) {
                  if (i === 0) {
                      stars += "<li style='position: relative;'><i class='star inactive'></i><i class='star' style='position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;overflow: hidden;width: "+width+"'></i></li>";
                  } else {
                      stars += "<li><i class='star inactive'></i></li>";
                  }
              };
            }
            stars += "</ul></div>";
            return stars;
        }

        var convertTime = function(UNIX_timestamp){
          var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
          var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
          var time = months[a.getMonth()] + ' ' + a.getDate() + ', ' + a.getFullYear();
          return time;
        }

        var addSchemaMarkup = function(element, placeData) {

          if(element instanceof jQuery){
            var schema = plugin.settings.schema;
            var schemaMarkup = '<span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/' + schema.type + '">';

            if(schema.image !== null) {
              schemaMarkup += generateSchemaItemMarkup('image', schema.image);
            } else {
              console.warn('Image is required for some schema types. Visit https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool to test your schema output.');
            }

            if(schema.priceRange !== null) {
              schemaMarkup += generateSchemaItemMarkup('priceRange', schema.priceRange);
            }

            schemaMarkup += generateSchemaItemMarkup('url', location.origin);
            schemaMarkup += generateSchemaItemMarkup('telephone', plugin.place_data.formatted_phone_number );
            schemaMarkup += generateSchemaAddressMarkup();
            schemaMarkup += generateSchemaRatingMarkup(placeData, schema);
            schemaMarkup += '</span>';

            element.append(schemaMarkup);
          }
        }

        var generateSchemaAddressMarkup = function() {
          var $address = $('<div />', {
              itemprop: "address"
            , itemscope: ''
            , itemtype: "http://schema.org/PostalAddress"
          }).css('display', 'none');
          $address.append(plugin.place_data.adr_address);
          $address.children('.street-address').attr('itemprop', 'streetAddress');
          $address.children('.locality').attr('itemprop', 'addressLocality');
          $address.children('.region').attr('itemprop', 'addressRegion');
          $address.children('.postal-code').attr('itemprop', 'postalCode');
          $address.children('.country-name').attr('itemprop', 'addressCountry');
          return $address[0].outerHTML;
        }

        var generateSchemaRatingMarkup = function(placeData, schema) {
          var reviews = placeData.reviews;
          var lastIndex = reviews.length - 1;
          var reviewPointTotal = 0;

          for (var i = lastIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
            reviewPointTotal += reviews[i].rating;
          };

          var averageReview = reviewPointTotal / ( reviews.length );

          return schema.beforeText + ' <span itemprop="name">' + placeData.name + '</span> '
          +  '<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">'
          +    '<span itemprop="ratingValue">' + averageReview.toFixed(2) + '</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> '
          +  schema.middleText + ' <span itemprop="ratingCount">' + reviews.length + '</span> '
          +  schema.afterText
          +  '</span>'
        }

        var generateSchemaItemMarkup = function(name, value) {
          return '<meta itemprop="' + name + '" content="' + value + '">'
        }

        plugin.init();

    }

    $.fn.googlePlaces = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data(namespace)) {
                var plugin = new $.googlePlaces(this, options);
                $(this).data(namespace, plugin);
            }
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I've also tried just this instead of everything above but still nothing displays.

html:

```
<div id="google-reviews"></div>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tutorialswebsite.com/cdn/google_places.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=APIKEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
        placeId: 'PLACEID' //Find placeID @: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id
      , render: ['reviews']
      , min_rating:3
      , max_rows:5
      ,rotateTime: false
      , shorten_names: true
 
     
   });
});
</script>
```

Edit: When I checked the console I received the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).googlePlaces is not a function TypeError: $(...).googlePlaces is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://orlhometech.netlify.app/reviews.html?:208:26)
    at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).googlePlaces is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (reviews.html:208)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
util.js:235 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SignedInNotSupported https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#signed-in-not-supported
Bv.j @ util.js:235
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBjy1orhutANXF-hI3r4LqJI2XeThpI1Dc&signed_in=true&libraries=places:168
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBjy1orhutANXF-hI3r4LqJI2XeThpI1Dc&signed_in=true&libraries=places:168
js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBjy1orhutANXF-hI3r4LqJI2XeThpI1Dc&signed_in=true&libraries=places:83 Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error
```

I don't know what all of that means but I'm pretty sure I created the api key correctly in the google console. Note this is for the second batch of code from my original post above, not the first batch.

Comment: How do you view this page? Do you need to run this on a local server?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: It is a live page running on a web host.

Comment: I posted the console errors in my edit above.

Comment: https://tutorialswebsite.com/cdn/google_places.js doesn't look to be a valid resource.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find the solution?